# Python 3.4 Emailing

Tags: python, email, ssl

I really cant seem to figure this out. Basically I am able to easily send an email to myself with python without a issue, now im going to be using an email server. Same kind of deal as using googles server to send an email. But im getting this dumb issue saying my SSL handshake is wrong even though im not even using SSL. Here is my code.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP ()
server.connect("mail.xxxxx.com:587")
server.set_debuglevel(True)

server.starttls()
server.ehlo()

server.login(sender, "xxxxx")

server.sendmail(sender, reciever[1], Msg)
```

So basically if I put mail.google or whatever it should work? It does but with my new mail it doesn't and I don't know why. Here is the error I am getting.

```
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_DECODE_ERROR] tlsv1 alert decode error (_ssl.c:600)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are calling `starttls`, which puts the connection in TLS mode.

Comment: But when I don't call it the email wont send, Even if I do call it the email doesn't send.

Comment: Ok, that's a different problem. You are using port 587. Try 25, which is commonly used for non-encrypted SMTP.

Comment: Haha I already have :) It still does not send, I honestly can't figure this out haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've stepped into the realm of trying to send emails in Python, please, try [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail). Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer, but I feel like it can help everyone out!

It really provides a lot of defaults: I'm quite sure you'll be able to send an email directly with:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('username', 'password') # possibly host and port arguments
yag.send(to_addrs, contents = msg)
```

You'll have to install `yagmail` first with either:

```
pip install yagmail  # python 2
pip3 install yagmail # python 3
```

Once you will want to also embed html/images or add attachments, you'll **really** love the package!

It will also make it a lot safer by preventing you from having to have your password in the code.

Comment: Wow this package is amazing.. Thank you so much!! I will recommend to everyone I know!!

Comment: @BSD_ Thanks a lot :)